# Why no mutable sorted map in Scala

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming

I have been looking for options to implement a mutable sorted map in scala. I know I can store my data in a mutable map and then transformed into a sorted map if is needed or wrap the TreeMap from Java. However, Does anyone know why this is not implemented in scala? Is against any functional programming style?

Regards

Comment: The 2 keys concepts of functionnal programming are 'function are objects' and 'immutability'

Comment: then, the best implementation should be to have a mutable map and then transform this map to a new one by sorting it. ?

Comment: However, @Jasper-M scala has mutable collections mutable.Map, etc.

Comment: Looks like it's implemented in 2.12: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0-M4/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/TreeMap.scala

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reason but the omission of writing one. In fact, [a mutable sorted map was added to Scala 2.12.x](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4504).

Answer (score 1):

There's some discussion in [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531856/why-is-there-no-mutable-treemap-in-scala) about possible reasons there isn't an implementation.

With regards to your second question, there are other mutable collections in Scala so I don't see any hard reason there couldn't be a mutable sorted map (see the older question as well). In a more general sense, functional programming can be taken to imply that mutable data is not used, and in this case a mutable sorted map would be avoided. However mutable collections may well be used "behind the scenes" in a library to improve performance, as long as they won't be visible to users of the library.